Reordering rows with javascript
I have multiple select dropdowns and each dropdown has a corresponding input field. What I'm trying to do is a JS function that will allow reordering the rows with icons UP/DOWN click.
What I'm trying to do also is simply for the first row to have only a DOWN icon, for the last row to have only a UP icon, and for everything else between them to have both UP and DOWN. What is happening is that I have UP and DOWN for the first and second rows and UP for the last one.
Here is the code that I have so far


$(document).ready(function () {

  function moveUp(index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    var $currentItem = $('[name="status[' + index + ']"]').closest('.line');
    var $prevItem = $('[name="status[' + (index - 1) + ']"]').closest('.line');
    $currentItem.insertBefore($prevItem);
    updateIconsVisibility();
  }

  function moveDown(index) {
    var $currentItem = $('[name="status[' + index + ']"]').closest('.line');
    var $nextItem = $('[name="status[' + (index + 1) + ']"]').closest('.line');
    $nextItem.insertAfter($currentItem);
    updateIconsVisibility();
  }

  function updateIconsVisibility() {
    $('.line').each(function (index, element) {
      var $line = $(element);
      var $arrows = $line.find('.arrows');
      var $upIcon = $arrows.find('.fa-chevron-circle-up');
      var $downIcon = $arrows.find('.fa-chevron-circle-down');

      if (index === 0) {
        $upIcon.hide();
        $downIcon.show();
      } else if (index === $('.line').length - 1) {
        $upIcon.show();
        $downIcon.hide();
      } else {
        $upIcon.show();
        $downIcon.show();
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.move-up-button', function() {
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    moveUp(index);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.move-down-button', function() {
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    moveDown(index);
  });

  updateIconsVisibility();
});
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mb-3"   id="dropdown-container-edit">
<div class="line" style="margin-top: 15px;display: flex;min-width: 329px;">
    <div style="float:left;display: flex; flex-direction: column;width: 10%;">
        <label for="select-group" class="form-label">Select Status</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="line" style="margin-top: 15px;display: flex;min-width: 329px;">
    <div style="float:left;display: flex; flex-direction: column;width: 10%;">
        <select class="select-group" name="status[0]">
            <option value="" data-id="">Select Status</option>
            <option value="0" data-id="" selected>Status_1</option>
            <option value="1" data-id="" >Status_2</option>
            <option value="2" data-id="" >Status_3</option>   
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 90%;">
        <input type="text" class="input-field status-input" name="status-input[0]" style="margin-left: 5px;" value="status_1">
    </div>
 
    <div class="arrows" style="display: inherit;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 3px; ">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up fa-2x move-up-button" data-index="0" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x move-down-button" data-index="0"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="line" style="margin-top: 15px;display: flex;min-width: 329px;">
    <div style="float:left;display: flex; flex-direction: column;width: 10%;">
        <select class="select-group" name="status[1]">
            <option value="" data-id="">Select Status</option>
            <option value="0" data-id="" >Status_1</option>
            <option value="1" data-id="" selected>Status_2</option>
            <option value="2" data-id="" >Status_3</option>   
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 90%;">
        <input type="text" class="input-field status-input" name="status-input[1]" style="margin-left: 5px;" value="status_2">
    </div>
 
    <div class="arrows" style="display: inherit;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 3px; ">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up fa-2x move-up-button" data-index="1" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x move-down-button" data-index="1"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="line" style="margin-top: 15px;display: flex;min-width: 329px;">
    <div style="float:left;display: flex; flex-direction: column;width: 10%;">
        <select class="select-group" name="status[2]">
            <option value="" data-id="">Select Status</option>
            <option value="0" data-id="" >Status_1</option>
            <option value="1" data-id="" >Status_2</option>
            <option value="2" data-id="" selected>Status_3</option>   
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 90%;">
        <input type="text" class="input-field status-input" name="status-input[2]" style="margin-left: 5px;" value="status_3">
    </div>
 
    <div class="arrows" style="display: inherit;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 3px; ">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up fa-2x move-up-button" data-index="2" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x move-down-button" data-index="2"></i>
    </div>
</div>
</div>



If Need here is the JSFiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/tm51dkra/2/

First problem i see is that you have 4 divs with class line that is the problem why the first "line" dont have an up arrow

Thanks for the input but the first row has UP arrow when it should have only DOWN since it is first..

The .line with index 0 doesn’t have any arrows (select status).

I've changed only a few things:
in your moveDown function you have this code: $nextItem.insertAfter($currentItem); but it should be $currentItem.insertAfter($nextItem);
I also remove class line from the first div.
<div class="" style="margin-top: 15px;display: flex;min-width: 329px;">
    <div style="float:left;display: flex; flex-direction: column;width: 10%;">
        <label for="select-group" class="form-label">Select Status</label>
    </div>
</div>

Because you use .line as a selector, like in:
function updateIconsVisibility() {
    $('.line').each(function (index, element) {

I've added an updateIndexes function to update the indexes, so they sorting will work.
Demo


$(document).ready(function() {

  function moveUp(index) {
    index = parseInt(index);
    if (index === 0) return;
    var $currentItem = $('[name="status[' + index + ']"]').closest('.line');
    var $prevItem = $('[name="status[' + (index - 1) + ']"]').closest('.line');
    $currentItem.insertBefore($prevItem);
    updateIndexes();
    updateIconsVisibility();
  }

  function moveDown(index) {
    index = parseInt(index);
    var $currentItem = $('[name="status[' + index + ']"]').closest('.line');
    var $nextItem = $('[name="status[' + (index + 1) + ']"]').closest('.line');
    if ($nextItem.length === 0) return;
    $currentItem.insertAfter($nextItem);
    updateIndexes();
    updateIconsVisibility();
  }
  
  function updateIndexes() {
    $('.line').each(function(i) {
      $(this).find('select[name^="status"]').attr('name', 'status[' + i + ']');
      $(this).find('input[name^="status-input"]').attr('name', 'status-input[' + i + ']');
      $(this).find('.move-up-button, .move-down-button').attr('data-index', i);
    });
  }

  function updateIconsVisibility() {
    $('.line').each(function(index) {
      var $upIcon = $(this).find('.fa-chevron-circle-up');
      var $downIcon = $(this).find('.fa-chevron-circle-down');

      if (index === 0) {
        $upIcon.hide();
      } else {
        $upIcon.show();
      }
      if (index === $('.line').length - 1) {
        $downIcon.hide();
      } else {
        $downIcon.show();
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.move-up-button', function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
    moveUp(index);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.move-down-button', function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
    moveDown(index);
  });
  updateIndexes();
  updateIconsVisibility();
});
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mb-3" id="dropdown-container-edit">
  <div class="" style="margin-top: 15px;display: flex;min-width: 329px;">
    <div style="float:left;display: flex; flex-direction: column;width: 10%;">
      <label for="select-group" class="form-label">Select Status</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="line" style="margin-top: 15px;display: flex;min-width: 329px;">
    <div style="float:left;display: flex; flex-direction: column;width: 10%;">
      <select class="select-group" name="status[0]">
        <option value="" data-id="">Select Status</option>
        <option value="0" data-id="" selected>Status_1</option>
        <option value="1" data-id="">Status_2</option>
        <option value="2" data-id="">Status_3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 90%;">
      <input type="text" class="input-field status-input" name="status-input[0]" style="margin-left: 5px;" value="status_1">
    </div>

    <div class="arrows" style="display: inherit;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 3px; ">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up fa-2x move-up-button" data-index="0" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x move-down-button" data-index="0"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="line" style="margin-top: 15px;display: flex;min-width: 329px;">
    <div style="float:left;display: flex; flex-direction: column;width: 10%;">
      <select class="select-group" name="status[1]">
        <option value="" data-id="">Select Status</option>
        <option value="0" data-id="">Status_1</option>
        <option value="1" data-id="" selected>Status_2</option>
        <option value="2" data-id="">Status_3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 90%;">
      <input type="text" class="input-field status-input" name="status-input[1]" style="margin-left: 5px;" value="status_2">
    </div>

    <div class="arrows" style="display: inherit;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 3px; ">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up fa-2x move-up-button" data-index="1" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x move-down-button" data-index="1"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="line" style="margin-top: 15px;display: flex;min-width: 329px;">
    <div style="float:left;display: flex; flex-direction: column;width: 10%;">
      <select class="select-group" name="status[2]">
        <option value="" data-id="">Select Status</option>
        <option value="0" data-id="">Status_1</option>
        <option value="1" data-id="">Status_2</option>
        <option value="2" data-id="" selected>Status_3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 90%;">
      <input type="text" class="input-field status-input" name="status-input[2]" style="margin-left: 5px;" value="status_3">
    </div>

    <div class="arrows" style="display: inherit;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 3px; ">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up fa-2x move-up-button" data-index="2" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x move-down-button" data-index="2"></i>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>




Thanks a lot. It's strange that it works here but not on the page. I copy/paste the generated HTML in the jsfiddle and it is working. Hm..

Oh, that's because I have class="line" in other divs before this container... silly me
